# Show images with same class as parent, which is the same as ID of list-item

Tags: jquery, toggle, each

**>>** [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/Mzdtg/) **<<**

```
var imgFilterBtn = $("nav > ul > li > ul > li > a");

$("img").fadeIn("slow");

imgFilterBtn.click(function() {
    var fadeInClass = $(this).attr("id");
    var wrongFilter = $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").children("li").children("a");

    wrongFilter.removeClass(); // un-style all links in one sub-list
    $(this).toggleClass("selected"); // style selected link


    var wrongFilterID = wrongFilter.attr("id");
    $("#imgWrap").removeClass(wrongFilterID); // remove all classes from imgWrap that are equal to an ID all LI-items in  the current list


    $("#imgWrap").toggleClass(fadeInClass); // toggle the class that is equal to the ID of the clicked a-element

    $("img").hide(); // hide all images

    var imgWrapClass = $("#imgWrap").attr("class");
    $("#imgWrap").children("img." + imgWrapClass).fadeIn("fast"); // fade in all elements that have the same class as imgWrap
});
```

I have done my best to include comments that explain what the script is doing.

**1. What works:**

- The images fade in on document load
- The "selected" class is toggled (but not toggled BACK!)
- The class on `#imgWrap` is toggled, but doesn't get toggled back
- Images are hidden and show when a list-item (actually its parent `li`) is clicked

---

**2. What does not work**

- When a li-item is clicked, the other classes don't get deleted
- Things mentioned above

---

**3. What should happen**
When a user clicks a link, the ID of that linked is passed on to a class which is assigned to `#imgWrap`. But before this class is assigned, all other classes that are the same as the ID's of other list items of THE SAME LIST (so not of another list) get deleted. So, when you click `black` and `fashion`, and then `brown` `#imgWrap` should have the classes `fashion` and `brown`, and `black` should have been deleted.

I am guessing I am missing an `each` function but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `wrongFilter` contains **all** `a` elements of that particular list and `wrongFilter.attr("id")` will **always** select the ID of the **first** selected element.

Regarding the toggling: If you select the element that is already selected, you first remove the `selected` class and then add it again. Similar to the class added to `#imgWrap`.

Restrict the selection to the actual selected element and fix the class adding/removal:

```
// ...
// Only get the currently selected element
var wrongFilter = $(this).closest('ul').find('a.selected');
var wrongFilterID = wrongFilter.attr("id"); // get its ID

// toggle `selected` for the previous selected element and the current one;
// will remove the class if the previous selected element is the same as the
// current one 
wrongFilter.add(this).toggleClass('selected');

// ...

// if the class already exists, the same menu entry was clicked and we have 
// to remove the class
$("#imgWrap").toggleClass(fadeInClass, wrongFilterID !== fadeInClass);

// ...
```

But now it can be that `wrongFilterID` is `undefined` and the next call to `removeClass` would remove all classes form `#imgWrap`. So you have to add a test:

```
if(wrongFilterID) {
    $("#imgWrap").removeClass(wrongFilterID); 
}
```

Another problem is that `imgWrapClass` can be a space delimited string of classes, e.g. `"fashion black"`, which means that

```
.children("img." + imgWrapClass)
```

will result in

```
.children("img.fashion black")
```

which is not what you want.

You have to create a proper selector from that string, e.g.:

```
// "fashion black" becomes "fashion.black"
var imgWrapClass = $.trim($("#imgWrap").attr("class")).replace(/\s+/g, '.');
```

---

With all that fixed, it seems to work properly:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mzdtg/7/)

Comment: I already thought that that was a problem (all a's being selected). I would never have come to that conclusion of the classes for #imgWrap though! Good thinking. Is there any chance that you have some links for a good explanation on regular expressions? I really don't know a lot about them, but would love to learn more. I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as I can! Oh and another question: what does the if-expression actually ask? Because I don't really understand why that works. Thanks again!

Comment: For regular expressions, I recommend http://www.regular-expressions.info/. Regarding the `if` statement: When no menu item is selected in a group, `wrongFilter` will be an empty set, hence `wrongFilter.attr("id")` will return `undefined`, since it cannot get the ID from any element. But passing `undefined` to `.removeClass` is the same as passing no arguments, which would remove *all* existing classes of the element. That's not what you want though. E.g. without the `if`, if you selected `Fashion` and later `black`, it would remove `fashion` as class, since no color was selected before.

Comment: `if(wrongFilterID)` just makes sure that `wrongFilterID` actually contains a non-empty string which can be removed form the class list.